# How to debug an exported variable from a dll?

Tags: c, visual-studio, debugging, dll

For my c project, I have some code which I'm building as a dll and within that dll I have a variable I'm exporting

```
#ifdef UI_EXPORT
#define UI_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define UI_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

//.....

extern UI_API ui_state _ui_state;

//In implementation file within dll project
ui_state _ui_state;
```

Everything compiles and seems to link fine when running my exe but I can't seem to debug the exported _ui_state variable from within my exe. Is there an additional step I need to do to debug this symbol? If I were to step into a function that calls into my dll then I can debug the variable

Comment: This could be due to optimization, but if the function accesses the variable then you should be able to see it in the debugger.

Comment: Maybe you're looking for the variable name? Rather than a static address passed into a register? I'm unsure if you have debugging symbols or how you're searching for the variable.